# Empty TDB2 Query Result

Tags: sparql, jena, tdb

I have a problem with the command line tools of Apache Jena. I want to create a tdb2 database for a big turtle file. For this reason I used the *tdb2.loader* command as follows:

```
tdb2.tdbloader --loc ~/indexer ~/indexer/test.ttl
```

My *test.ttl* file contains entries of the form:

```
@prefix bbase: <http://data.bibbase.org/ontology/#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dblp:  <https://dblp.org/rdf/schema-2017-04-18#> 

<https://dblp.org/rec/conf/romoco/Siegwart13>
    a                              dblp:Publication ;
    owl:sameAs                     <http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/RoMoCo.2013.6614591> ;
    dblp:authoredBy                <https://dblp.org/pers/s/Siegwart:Roland> ;
    dblp:bibtexType                bbase:Inproceedings ;
    dblp:listedOnTocPage           <https://dblp.org/db/conf/romoco/romoco2013> ;
    dblp:pageNumbers               "98" ;
    dblp:primaryElectronicEdition  <https://doi.org/10.1109/RoMoCo.2013.6614591> ;
    dblp:doi                       "10.1109/RoMoCo.2013.6614591";
    dblp:publicationType           dblp:Inproceedings ;
    dblp:publishedAsPartOf         <https://dblp.org/rec/conf/romoco/2013> ;
    dblp:publishedInBook           "RoMoCo" ;
    dblp:title                     "Design and navigation of wheeled, running, swimming and flying robots." ;
    dblp:yearOfPublication         "2013" .
...
```

Now my problem is that if I query the output (tdb2 file), by using the *tdb2.tdbquery* command, an empty table will be the result. My query searches for all entities having a *dblp:doi* property and the result should not be an empty table as you can see on the example above. My query file looks als follows:

```
PREFIX dblp:  <https://dblp.org/rdf/schema-2017-04-18#>

SELECT *
WHERE{
  ?s dblp:doi ?o .
}
```

And my my *tdb2.query* command looks as follows:

```
./tdb2.tdbquery --loc=~/indexer/Data-0001 --query=~/indexer/query.rq
```

No matter what I'm doing, my result is always:

```
---------
| s | o |
=========
---------
```

If I query the .ttl-files directly with the sparql command in the same manner as I use the *tdb2.query* command, I will get a reasonable result containing some entries.

Unfortunately I cannot find an answer to my question, neither in the Jena documentation nor in this forum. Can someone give me an answer or at least a hint what might go wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Works for me with Jena 3.7.0 - why did you change the path of the database in the command with the query? Clearly it must be the same as for loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `--loc` parameter on the query should be the location where you created the TDB2 database i.e. ~/indexer